# Ошибка при использовании Kivy>Spinner>on_value:

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

my.kv
:

```
first: first
second: second
button: button
spin: spin

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: first
        hint_text: 'электродвижущая сила (a)'
        multiline: False
        input_type: 'number'
        input_filter: 'float'

    TextInput:
        id: second
        hint_text: 'сопротивление внешней цепи (R)'
        multiline: False
        input_type: 'number'
        input_filter: 'float'


    Spinner:
        id: spin
        values: 'I=U/R','U=I*R','R=U/I'
        text: 'I=U/R'
        on_value:
            root.check_spinner()

    Button:
        id: button
        text: 'Start'
        on_release:
            root.do_oma()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 725, in _apply_rule
     raise AttributeError(key)
 AttributeError: value
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 42, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "main.py", line 39, in build
     return Container()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/uix/boxlayout.py", line 145, in __init__
     super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 361, in __init__
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 734, in _apply_rule
     '{}: {}'.format(e.__class__.__name__, e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/freedge/main_folder_test/my.kv", line 30:
 ...
      28:           text: 'I=U/R'
      29:           on_value:
 >>   30:               root.check_spinner()
      31:
      32:       Button:
 ...
 AttributeError: value
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 725, in _apply_rule
     raise AttributeError(key)
```

Linux Mint 19.3,python3.
Возникает она при попытке использовать on_value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, `on_value` устарело и теперь нужно использовать `on_text`, попробуйте:

```
        on_text:
            root.check_spinner()
```

[Пример из репозитория kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/06862dbcf852f6e35a440a04235eecd059dce84d/kivy/uix/spinner.py#L47):

```
    FloatLayout:
        Spinner:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 100, 44
            pos_hint: {'center': (.5, .5)}
            text: 'Home'
            values: 'Home', 'Work', 'Other', 'Custom'
            on_text:
                print("The spinner {} has text {}".format(self, self.text))
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!